# Windows 2003 Admin Pack - Version/Replacement compatable with Win 7 Pro 32-bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003

I just upgraded my laptop from XP Pro to Win 7 Pro 32-bit version and I need to install the Windows Server 2003 Administration Tools Pack but the site and the installer say it is not compatible with this version of Windows. Do you know of any replacements or workarounds for this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to install with compatibility settings set to XP?

Comment: The installer is an .msi file - I didn't see compatibility settings for the .msi file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7D2F6AD7-656B-4313-A005-4E344E43997D&displaylang=en)?

Or have I missed the point of what you want?

Comment: Those are for 2008 he needs 2003 tools.

Comment: I'm looking in to this now but it's a 221 MB download - please be patient ;)

Comment: It works with 2003 and 2008 - it say's so at the top of the page when you click on the link.

Comment: You nailed it!! Also wanted to add that after I installed the software and completed the directions I had to reboot to get the programs to run. I didn't see anything about rebooting.